# How to use Graph API to get user's total friend count [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, html, json, facebook-graph-api

After doing some research into Facebook's Graph API v2.8, I finally understand how to craft functions using **JavaScript**. What I would like to specifically do is after I have the user logged into my application, they would click a button that grabs a total of their friend count.

Here is the code I'm attempting to use to accomplish this:

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="getInfo()">Get Friend Count</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Get Basic User Info
// TODO: Get user's friend count
function getInfo() {
FB.api('/me/friends', 'GET', {
    fields: 'total_count'
}, function (response) {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = response.id;
});
}
```

Perhaps the fields parameter is wrong?
The ultimate goal is that I want the total count of friends publicly displayed on a user's profile within my application.

**EDIT:** `user_friends` has been authorized with the access token that I generated, but my response.id comes back as undefined.

**EDIT 2:** The data returned using the Graph API Explorer comes in a **JSON** format:

```
{
"id": "my_id",
"name": "my_name",
"friends": {
"data": [
],
"summary": {
  "total_count": 161
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: This was the best reference I was able to get:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends

Comment: The fields parameter is unnecessary, total_count is returned in any case. What’s wrong is your assumption that there was an `id` property on the response. Log the response object to console and inspect it there, or make the request in [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to see what kind of data structure you actually get.

Comment: @CBroe I'll give `console.log` a shot to see what the result is. The data you get from the Graph API itself it in JSON format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Please note that I wrote this in 2017, and the API may have changed since then, especially after the whole Cambridge Analytica thing.**

Good news! I solved it by digging deeper into some source code that I found at this site: http://snowadays.jp/test/fb_friend_test.html

Here is the **JavaScript**:

```
function getInfo() {
FB.api('/me/friends', 'GET', {fields: 'summary'}, function(response)
{
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 
response.summary.total_count;
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your apps needs `user_friends` authorization, and note that **only friends who installed the app are returned in API v2.0 and higher**.
Before using Javascript SDK i suggest to do some testings with the [Graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I had already authorized that via the access token. But my response.id comes back as undefined

Comment: do you have any friends using the app?

Comment: total_count returns the count of all friends, not only those that are users of the same app.

Comment: @NicolòCozzani I have no friends using the app just yet. The idea is that they would create an account using their Facebook information if they so choose, and then be able to pull other data into their public profile.

Comment: @CBroe When someone logs into my app by using Facebook, or even connects it later - I want their number of friends to be displayed on their public profile on my application. I've seen this done before, but not sure how to use the Graph API to achieve this.

Comment: @CBroe you are right, you can see total count, but you can see info only of users that use the app. my bad