# Storing data from Facebook's Graph API

Tags: database, facebook-graph-api, web, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

For the past two days, I finally was able to understand how to extract data from Facebook's **Graph API**.

[How to use Graph API to get user's total friend count [JavaScript]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124438/how-to-use-graph-api-to-get-users-total-friend-count-javascript)

Awesome, right? Now, for the next part.

I want to be able to store this data so that it can be publicly displayed on a user's profile within the application I am developing.

Here is the flow that I am thinking:

- User goes to create an account on my application
- User is asked via OAuth to pull in their Facebook data such as their profile picture, friend count, etc.
- Their data is stored and synced to be always up-to-date [***this is what I am trying to figure out***]
- The data stored is publicly displayed on their profile (such as their friend count)

Comment: Facebook has Webhooks to notify apps of changes - but that does not cover user friends, I think. So in that case you only have the option to poll in regular intervals.

Comment: So I figured out what I was trying to achieve. Back in Feb. I knew nothing about databases - so all I had to do was store data in something like `mysql` or `nosql` and just spit the data back out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never went back to this - but from my understanding now versus what I knew back when I posted this; all one would need to do is store the data in a database so it can be spit back out- and it would just be associated to the user.